# Finitely additivity and continuity from above at $\varnothing$ implies countably additivity.

Tags: measure-theory

I know that given a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$, if a finitely additive set function $\mu$ is **finite** and continuous from above at $\varnothing$, then $\mu$ is a measure. But what if $\mu (\Omega)=\infty$? Could you please prove it or give a counterexample?

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please,  upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counter-example.

Let $\Omega = \Bbb N$ and  $\mathcal F= 2^{\Bbb N}$. Define $\mu$ on $\mathcal F$ by:
$\mu(E)= 0$ if $E$ is finite  and $\mu(E)= +\infty$  if $E$ is infinite.

Note that $\mu(\Omega) = +\infty$.

It is easy to see that $\mu$ is finitely additive and $\mu$ is continuous from above at $\emptyset$. BUT $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-additive.

**Remark**. Recall the definition: A set function $\mu$ is *continuous from above at $\emptyset$*  if given any decreasing sequence $E_1 \supseteq E_2\supseteq E_3 \supseteq ... $ of sets in $\mathcal F$ such that $\bigcap_n E_n = \emptyset$, if there is at least one $n$ such that $\mu(E_n)< +\infty$, then $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \mu(E_n) =0$.

Comment: @Gae It is continuous from above at $\emptyset$. The definition of "continuous from above at $\emptyset$" requires that at least one of the sets in the decreasing sequence has finite measure.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought it wasn't demanded.